# How to add ButtonOverlay on a Map(osmdroid)

Tags: android-studio, osmdroid

I want to add a button overlay but it shouldn't be based on the geopoint but instead based on the screen. So whenever i scroll the map, the button should still exists and will remain in that position, How do i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add it to your android layout for the activity/fragment

Example here:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/res/layout/sample_cachemgr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tilesource="Mapnik" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCache"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Cache Manager"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it doesn't support it thus, it do not display

Comment: Android supports it, so why would osmdroid rewrite the button

Comment: android draws stuff on screen in the order they are referenced in the layout xml, so stuff towards the bottom of the layout is usually drawn on top whatever is toward the top of the xml